# remove null values and merge sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, null

I have a table (TestTable) as follows

```
PK  |  COL1  |  COL2  |  COL3  
1   |  3    |  NULL  |  NULL    
2   |  3    |  43    |  1.5     
3   |  4    |  NULL  |  NULL    
4   |  4    |  NULL  |  NULL    
5   |  4    |  48    |  10.5    
6   | NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  
7   | NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  
8   | NULL  |  NULL  |  NULL  
9   | 5     |  NULL  |  NULL  
10  | 5     |  NULL  |  NULL  
11  | 5     |  55    |  95
```

I would like a result as follows

```
PK  |  COL1  |  COL2  |  COL3  
1   |  3     |  43    |  1.5    
2   |  4     |  48    |  10.5    
3   |  5     |  55    |  95
```

Comment: How you are suppose to combine the values of different rows without a relation.

Comment: Would your test table need to consider that COL2 has a value but COL3 does not? And then merge that with COL3 having a value and COL2 does not?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, But it won't give you a serial number for the `PK`:

```
SELECT 
    PK,
    MAX(Col1) AS Col1,
    MAX(Col2) AS Col2,
    MAX(Col3) AS Col3
  FROM TestTable
  WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
    AND Col2 IS NOT NULL 
    AND COL3 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY PK;


| PK | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
|----|------|------|------|
|  2 |    3 |   43 |  1.5 |
|  5 |    4 |   48 | 10.5 |
| 11 |    5 |   55 |   95 |
```

If you want to generate a rownumber for the column pk, you can do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT 
    PK,
    MAX(Col1) AS Col1,
    MAX(Col2) AS Col2,
    MAX(Col3) AS Col3
  FROM TestTable
  WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
    AND Col2 IS NOT NULL 
    AND COL3 IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY PK
), Ranked 
AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PK) AS RN
  FROM CTE;
 )
SELECT RN AS PK, Col1, COL2, COL3 FROM Ranked
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31dc1/3)

This will give you:

```
| PK | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
|----|------|------|------|
|  1 |    3 |   43 |  1.5 |
|  2 |    4 |   48 | 10.5 |
|  3 |    5 |   55 |   95 |
```

Comment: Since you are grouping by PK and PK is unique, you are not aggregating anything and will have exactly the output as the input.

Comment: @JasonW - Please see my updated answer, and check the demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31dc1/3

Answer (score 0):

This can be obtained in two steps like so:

1st step: Get rid of unnecessary rows:

```
delete from testTable 
where Col1 is null
    or Col2 is null
    or Col3 is null
```

2nd step: Set the correck PK values using a CTE (update test table):

```
;with sanitizeCTE 
as(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by PK) as PK,
        Col1, Col2, Col3
from testTable
)
update t
set t.PK = CTE.PK
from testTable t
join sanitizeCTE cte
on t.Col1 = cte.Col1
    and t.Col2 = cte.Col2
    and t.Col3 = cte.Col3
```

Tested here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91e86/1